# R regex match whole word taking punctuation into account

Tags: r, regex, string-matching

I'm in R. I want to match whole words in text, *taking punctuation into account*.
Example:

```
to_match = c('eye','nose')
text1 = 'blah blahblah eye-to-eye blah'
text2 = 'blah blahblah eye blah'
```

I would like `eye` to be matched in `text2` but not in `text1`.

That is, the command:

```
to_match[sapply(paste0('\\<',to_match,'\\>'),grepl,text1)]
```

should return `character(0)`. But right now, it returns `eye`.

I also tried with `'\\b'` instead of `'\\<'`, with no success.

Comment: Use `to_match[sapply(paste0('(?:^|\\s)',to_match,'(?:\\s|$)'),grepl,text1)]`

Comment: thanks much, it works! If you turn your comment into an answer (maybe with a few explanations of what the regex does) I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
to_match[sapply(paste0('(?:\\s|^)',to_match,'(?:\\s|$)'),grepl,text1)]
```

The point is that word boundaries match between a word and a nonword chars, that is why you had a match in `eye-to-eye`. You want to match only in between start or end of string and whitespace.

In a TRE regex, this is better done with groups as this regex library does not support lookarounds and you just need to test a string for a single pattern match to return true or false.

The `(?:\s|^)`  noncapturing group matches any whitespace or start of string and `(?:\s|$)` matches whitespace or end of string.